# Script to retrieve the (large) contents of a Rackspace cloud files container?

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace, rackspace-cloudfiles

I've decided that Cloud Files is getting too expensive for me now that I'm approaching 1TB of files, and it'll be silly when I get to 2-3TB within a year, so I'm going down the dedicated box route instead.

Can someone point me to a simple/bulletproof way to download 600,000 items from a container? I've searched around and found conflicting advice of the best way to do this, but figured I trust this community more than most random pages that google throws up!

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to rearchitect your app to use your own object store? How do you plan on doing backups?

Comment: I am yes.  Backups are undediced at the moment if I'm honest.  Amazon Glacier looks cheap but very spendy if you actually NEED to restore, unless you're happy to spend a week or two doing it.  Which actually, for this use (an archive of photos) wouldn't be the end of the world.

Other options are a second webhost that I rsync to, or rsyncing to drives on my home PC.  Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had good success with [turbolift](https://github.com/cloudnull/turbolift) for rapidly uploading or downloading large batches of files.